# nginx reverse proxy fails for post/get requests

Tags: node.js, express, nginx, reverse-proxy

I'm trying to set up a reverse proxy using nginx for a nodejs application. My node application currently runs on port 8005 of the example.com server. Running the application and going to example.com:8005 the application works perfect. But When I tried to set up nginx my application seems to work at first by going to example.com/test/ but when I try and post or get requests the request wants to use the example.com:8005 url and I end up with a cross origin error, CORS. I would like to have the request url reflect the nginx url but I'm having no luck getting there. Below is my nginx default.conf file.

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  example;

    location / {
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
        index  index.html index.htm;
    }

    error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
    }

   location /test/ {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:8005/;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }
}
```

Comment: are your post/get requests prefixed with '/test/' (are they falling in to the /test/ location block)?

Comment: @roger no my posts aren't prefixed with anything

Comment: If that's the case, I'd guess they're being caught by the '/' location block, (which is currently serving static files).  If you want them picked up by your node process you'll want to make sure those requests are hitting a location block with proxy_pass http://localhost:8005/

Comment: Also if you want your request to hit this configuration, it's listening on port 80 (not 8005) so in your request dont use :8005 at the end of the url

Comment: I'm doing a simple form submit post from an html page that is being hosted by the node app on port 8005. I was hoping nginx would let me hide the port  and eventually let me host multiple apps under example.com/test, example.com/test2, etc

Comment: it can! try sending a request/setting your form action to hit example.com/test/yourtestendpoint (dont add port 8005 to the end, let nginx handle that, like you are already doing in your /test/ location block)

Comment: Ok. I'll give a try and post back. But does this mean that my apps will no longer work without using nginx?

Comment: Changing the calls to test/postcall did not work.

Answer (score 1):

There got to be some way to tell nginx about whichever app you are using.

So for that, either you can prefix all the apis with say test`(location /test/api_uri`), and then catch all the urls with prefix /test and proxy_pass them to node, or if there is some specific pattern in your urk, you can catch that pattern with regex, like suppose, all the app1 apis contain app1 somewhere in it, then catch those urls using `location ~ /.*app1.* {} location ~ /.*app2.*`, make sure that you maintain the [order](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location) of location.

Demo Code :

```
server {
   ...
   location /test {
      proxy_pass http://localhost:8005/; #app1
      proxy_http_version 1.1;
      proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
      proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
      proxy_set_header Host $host;
      proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
   }
   location /test2 {
      proxy_pass http://localhost:8006/; #app2
      proxy_http_version 1.1;
      proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
      proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
      proxy_set_header Host $host;
      proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
   }
   ...
}
```

Other Demo for regex,

```
server {
   ...
   location ~ /.*app1.* {
      proxy_pass http://localhost:8005/; #app1
      proxy_http_version 1.1;
      proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
      proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
      proxy_set_header Host $host;
      proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
   }
   location ~ /.*app2.* {
      proxy_pass http://localhost:8006/; #app2
      proxy_http_version 1.1;
      proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
      proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
      proxy_set_header Host $host;
      proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
   }
   ...
}
```